# Unable to Scroll using Flatlist in React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

So i have tried couple of things, data pulled from the REST api works fine without trouble, but when i put it to Flatlist, it does not scroll. Tried countless things I saw on the internet, and still , it does not seem to work.

Below is a snippet i used, to display data from the REST api to the application :

```
      <View>
    {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : <FlatList 
      style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', top: 170, left: 23}}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
      data={transaction_details}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={{paddingTop: 20,flexDirection: 'row', height: 75}}>
          <Image source={{uri: item.avatar}} style={{width:50, height:50, borderRadius:25,overflow:'hidden'}}/>
          <Text style={styles.PayeeName}>{item.name}{"   "}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.date_ofTransaction}>{item.date}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.amountValue}>{item.amount}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id .toString()}
      scrollEnabled={true}
    />}

  </View>
```

Looking over, i saw something like `View style={{flex:1}}` should I have to try this, the whole thing disappears speedily. I dont know what else I have to try hence, this.

I need help with this.
Thank you!

**New Edits**

done the edit you asked me to, now there are still some spaces there. Do not know how they came about,

I looks like this now so far

[image: Screenshot-1667927962.png]

Here is the new Source code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Avatar, Icon, Card} from '@rneui/themed';
import {FlatList, ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Tab} from '@rneui/base';


const HomePage = () => {
  const [transaction_details, setTransaction_details] = useState([]);
  const[isLoading,setLoading] = useState(true);

  const Item = ({title}) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: 350,
          backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, borderWidth:1}}>
      <Header
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
        }}
        leftComponent={
          <Avatar
            small
            rounded
            source={{
              uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSiRne6FGeaSVKarmINpum5kCuJ-pwRiA9ZT6D4_TTnUVACpNbzwJKBMNdiicFDChdFuYA&usqp=CAU',
            }}
            onPress={() => console.log('Left Clicked!')}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
          />
        }
        rightComponent={
          <Icon
            name={'add-circle-outline'}
            color={'#00BB23'}
            size={32}
            onPress={() => console.log('Right Clicked!')}
          />
        }></Header>
      <View 
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderadius: 9,
          alignItems: 'center',
          borderWidth:1
        }}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: 'asset:/logo/bg.JPG',
          }}
          imageStyle={{borderRadius: 6}}
          style={{
            width: 350,
            height: 150,
            borderadius: 9,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.accText}>Wallet Balance</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}> 250,000 </Text>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      <View style={{borderWidth:1}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            fontSize: 15,
            left: 18,
            color: 'gray',
          }}>
          Recent Transactions
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1, borderWidth:1}}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : <FlatList
          style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', left: 23}}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          data={transaction_details}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Image source={{uri: item.avatar}} style={{width:50, height:50, borderRadius:25,overflow:'hidden'}}/>
              <Text style={styles.PayeeName}>{item.name}{"   "}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.date_ofTransaction}>{item.date}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.amountValue}>{item.amount}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id .toString()}
        />}

      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  date_ofTransaction: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems:'flex-start',
    alignItems:'center',
    left: -75,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Light',
    size: 4,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  text: {
    top: -85,
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
  },
  mainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 90,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  accText: {
    top: -85,
    paddingTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  PayeeName: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems:'center',
    left: 23,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    size: 800,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  amountValue: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    alignItems:'center',
    right: -25,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    size: 800,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

It does not scroll because your view is restricting it. Try replacing view with <></> (Fragments).

### Method 2

The other way of solving this is adding flex 1 in view container, it disappears because its parent also needs to be set to flex. So find all parents that have view in it and add flex 1 in them Then it will work

Comment: Solved it, but it cuts and creates something like a height and i do not want any height now, do i share my full source code so you take a good look at it pls?

Comment: Can you show the output, and show how you want it to be

Comment: please see edits.

Comment: Just remove the top:-155

Comment: i did , then it creates the gap on the place before recent transactions pls see edits

Comment: remove top-155 from recent transactions text

Comment: To debug correctly, see what is taking that space, give borderWidth:1 to each container and see what is causing it

Comment: Did the debugging as you said, Please see edits

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, just remove the flex:1 from View containing image background

Comment: i have done that , there is still some space around the image background. Please see edits

Comment: removing the view as container of background will remove all space, if you want to control amount of space try increasing number of flex, change flex to 2 of the list container